# Access my latops XAMPP directories from smartphone without a router

Tags: networking, xampp, smartphone, access-point

I'm working on a website whose main purpose is to be accessed from mobile phones. On my laptop I've installed XAMPP and work with it for development. If I want to check one of the websites from my Android Smartphone, so it connects through my home or work wireless network, which gave my laptop an internal IP.
I do not always have that network though, so my smartphone would need to find my laptop without that. Do I need to turn my laptop into an access point, so my smartphone can find and connect over a SSID or is there a different way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can use an application like [localtunnel](http://progrium.com/localtunnel/) to tunnel your laptop's webserver over the Internet.
- You can connect your laptop and smartphone to the same network: by
  USB/Bluetooth/Wifi tethering, or by a shared external network.

Comment: localtunnel wouldm ost likely solve it, but my laptop has windows 7, and it's not written for that.

Comment: (sorry, I couldn't edit my previous message anymore)
I tried Bluetooth but there must be a problem with my smartphone. However, the simplest idea was connecting via USB and it worked, no idea why I didn't think of that before. Thanks for help!

Comment: looks like there's also a localtunnel client for windows: https://github.com/danielrmz/localtunnel-net-client

Comment: You're right, but I didn't come too far with that one, it gave me quite a big error. The USB way works as it should, so I don't need to find solutions now.